# cakephp session.cooke_lifetime doesn't work

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using this configuration in core.php:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'php'
    ));

Configure::write('Session.save', 'custom_session_handler');

/**
 * The level of CakePHP security.
 */
Configure::write('Security.level', 'high');
```

And custom_session_handler.php (in app/config)

```
<?php

    ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0); 

?>
```

When I close browser session should be destroyed/not remembered - but it doesn't work, when I close browser I am still logged in...

I am using Auth component, cakePHP 2.0, php 5.3.9 on WAMP server on my PC.
And moreover in my php.ini Session.cookie_lifetime is set to 0 by default

Answer (score 1):

I found it - it should be:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'php',
        'cookieTimeout' => 0,
    ));
```